# Right way of using getline() with struct and string data type

Tags: c++, string, struct

I am trying to get the name of the student declared of a struct data type with getline() but I am not sure how to do that.

```
int main () {
struct student {
      string rollnumber;
    string name;
string batch;
};
student  s1;
cout<<" enter name of student ";
cin.getline(s1.name,string);
}
```

I am getting this error.

error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token

14 | cin.getline(s1.name,string);

what should I do?

Comment: `cin.getline(s1.name,string);` <-- it is't clear why you need this last `string` here. Try removing it. Also you probably need a free function rather than a member function of the same name, so `getline(cin, s1.name)`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. tried this but still not working

Comment: What exactly does "not working" mean?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. It's working I made a small syntax error I just noticed thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Biggest thing is that's the wrong getline. One of the fun quirks of the language.